# I made a my own theme to WordPress and Admin Menu missing from frontend

Tags: theme-development

I made a my own theme to WordPress and Admin Menu missing from frontend.

How to fix this?

Comment: You're probably missing the wp_footer function.

Comment: @Milo Please include your suggestion as an answer, so it can be accepted and this question be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should keep the below code in your theme( header.php file ).

```
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Something looks likes the below in header.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Lastly, You need to put the following code in your footer.php, before closing  tag

```
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

The code looks like these

```
   <?php wp_footer(); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```